# I need a suggestion for how to create a SQL instead a function for this case (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

This is for a SQL Server 2016 database.

I have two tables, like below:

**Table A**:

- GlobalId uniqueidentifier,
- Date datetime2,
- Description

**Table B**:

- GlobalId uniqueidentifier,
- Rel_GlobalId uniqueidentifier,
- Filename nvarchar(250),
- Date datetime2

The relationship between table A and table B is 1-to-many, or 'A row on Table A contain one or more rows from Table B'

B always contain one or more rows that belongs to A. But I need only the first and the last rows (sorted by Date from Table B), so, even a row on Table A has 10 rows from Table B, I need only the first and the last rows from B. If A has only 1 B, I need only the first B.

I must return the value in the following format:

```
GlobalId (from A), First_File (GlobalId from B), Last_File (GlobalID from B), First_File_Num*, Last_File_Num*
```

The `First_File_Num` and `Last_File_Num` is a sequential number, starting from 1 to infinite, but this is a single sequential number. If A has two B, first_file_num = 1, and last_file_num = 2. On consecutive rows, that sequential number must continue from last row, so, must be 3 and 4, then 5 and 6, etc. But if A has only on B, the increment is only 1 for this row.

To make things more clear (and because English is not my primary language), take this as example:

**Table A**:

```
+----------+------------+----------------+
| GlobalId | Date       | Description    |
+----------+------------+----------------+
| aa       | 2016-12-06 | Description 01 |
| ab       | 2016-12-07 | Description 02 |
| ac       | 2016-12-07 | Description 03 |
+----------+------------+----------------+
```

**Table B**:

```
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+
| GlobalId | Rel_GlobalId | Filename   | Date                |
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+
| ba       | aa           | file02.jpg | 2016-12-06 05:13:25 |
| bb       | aa           | file01.jpg | 2016-12-06 03:45:12 |
| bc       | ab           | file03.jpg | 2016-12-07 08:54:31 |
| bd       | ac           | file05.jpg | 2016-12-07 11:39:19 |
| be       | ac           | file04.jpg | 2016-12-07 10:48:13 |
| bf       | ac           | file06.jpg | 2016-12-07 15:08:17 |
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+
```

The relationship between Table A and Table B is `A.GlobalId = B.Rel_GlobalId`

So, now, I must return a table with the following data:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+
| GlobalId | First_File | Last_File | First_File_Num | Last_File_Num |
+----------+------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+
| aa       | bb         | ba        | 01             | 02            |
| ab       | bc         | NULL      | 03             | NULL          |
| ac       | be         | bf        | 04             | 05            |
+----------+------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+
```

To resolve this problem, I have created a function (table valued function), but I like to know if this is possible only with views (even I have to create more than one view) - just for curiosity :D

Comment: you can use two row_numbers(), one with Date asc one with Date desc. Put it in a subquery/CTE, and select where both row_numbers are 1.

Comment: And where do you get the sequential number for `First_File_Num` and `Last_File_Num`? Are they in Table B already? Or are they in the FileName?

Comment: @DVT They are nowhere. It's a sequential number that must be 'calculate' on-the-fly. It's just a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/* I need a suggestion for how to create a SQL instead a function for this case (SQL Server) */
[I need a suggestion for how to create a SQL instead a function for this case (SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025139/i-need-a-suggestion-for-how-to-create-a-sql-instead-a-function-for-this-case-sq#41025139)

You can do this using a `cte` and using multiple `row_number()`s (like HoneyBadger said in his comment).

rextester:http://rextester.com/FHQIL42952

```
create table a (
    globalid    varchar(36)  not null primary key
  , date        datetime2(2) not null
  , description varchar(128) not null
);
create table b (
    rel_globalid varchar(36)  not null
  , globalid     varchar(36)  not null
  , filename     varchar(128) not null
  , date         datetime2(2) not null
);
insert into a (globalid, date, description) values
  ('aa','2016-12-06','Description 01')
, ('ab','2016-12-07','Description 02')
, ('ac','2016-12-07','Description 03');

insert into b (globalid, rel_globalid, filename, date) values
 ('ba','aa','file02.jpg','2016-12-06T05:13:25')
,('bb','aa','file01.jpg','2016-12-06T03:45:12')
,('bc','ab','file03.jpg','2016-12-07T08:54:31')
,('bd','ac','file05.jpg','2016-12-07T11:39:19')
,('be','ac','file04.jpg','2016-12-07T10:48:13')
,('bf','ac','file06.jpg','2016-12-07T15:08:17');

with cte as (
  select 
      globalid
    , rel_globalid
    , filename
    , date
    , rn_a = row_number() over (partition by rel_globalid order by date asc)
    , rn_d = row_number() over (partition by rel_globalid order by date desc)
  from b
  )
, x as (
  select 
      globalid
    , rel_globalid
    , filename
    , date
    , rn_a
    , rn_d
    , seq = row_number() over (order by globalid, date asc)
  from cte
  where rn_a = 1 
    or  rn_d = 1
  )

  select 
      a.globalid
    , first_file     = ba.globalid
    , last_file      = bd.globalid
    , first_file_num = ba.seq
    , last_file_num  = bd.seq
    from a
      left join x as ba on a.globalid = ba.rel_globalid and ba.rn_a = 1
      left join x as bd on a.globalid = bd.rel_globalid and bd.rn_d = 1 and bd.rn_a !=1
    order by a.globalid;
```

Results in:

```
globalid    first_file    last_file   first_file_num  last_file_num
aa            bb            ba            1            2
ab            bc            NULL          3            NULL
ac            be            bf            4            5
```

Comment: Tks. I don't know the 'with cte'. But on your results, on the last row (globalid = ac), first_file_num is 4, and last_file_num is 6. The last_file_num must be 5.

Comment: @Roberto-Correia I corrected the file numbers using another `cte` More about `cte`s: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would rather create a function that returns the last row of a record and then create a stored procedure that returns the first row and make a cross apply to the function, the apply operator is very useful and because it no work as inner joins the impact in the select query is very low